# Найти и удалить объект по его Uid/Name. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется Canvas, для него есть несколько дочерних объектов Image с прописанными Uid/Name.
Возможно ли из кода бихаинд найти заданные Image по Uid/Name и удалить их из Canvas?

Comment: А почему не MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно удалить по 1 элементу, то можно попробовать что то по типу:

```
var image = canvas1.Children.OfType<Image>().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == "Image1"); //В нашем canvas (c именем canvas1) находим объект типа Image с именем Image1.
canvas1.Children.Remove(image); //Удаляем из canvas1 дочерний элемент, найденный ранее.
```

---

Можно взять все элементы из `canvas1`, преобразовать их в `List` и пройтись по дочерним элементам циклом:

```
var images = canvas1.Children.OfType<Image>().ToList(); //Все элементы типа Image в нашем подопытном canvas1
foreach (var image in images)
{
    if (image.Name == "Image1") //Соответствие на имя.
        canvas1.Children.Remove(image); //Удаляем
}
```