# Как найти и удалить программно созданный объект в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я динамично создаю объект, который позже нужно будет удалить, но когда я пытаюсь его удалить по имени, у меня нечего не выходит.

Пример удаления нашёл здесь -> [Найти и удалить объект по его Uid/Name. WPF C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707919/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-uid-name-wpf-c)

```
var Failure_Message = NotificationPanel.Children.OfType<GroupBox>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MMF_Failure");
NotificationPanel.Children.Remove(Failure_Message);
```

UPD: Новый элемент создаётся у меня так:

```
GroupBox MMF_Failure = new GroupBox();
                MMF_Failure.Name = "MMF_Failure";
                StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
                Label TEMP = new Label();
                TEMP.Content += "Не вдалося відкрити файл";
                TEMP.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                panel.Children.Add(TEMP);
                Button MMF_Retry = new Button();
                MMF_Retry.Content = "Повторити спробу";
                MMF_Retry.Click += OpenMMF;
                panel.Children.Add(MMF_Retry);
                MMF_Failure.Content = panel;
                NotificationPanel.Children.Add(MMF_Failure);
```

Comment: И какой-же элемент требуется удалить?

Comment: @Bulson обратите внимание на `x.Name == "MMF_Failure"`. Но здесь настолько всё тяжко, что я воздержусь от советов автору. Могу только сказать, что код для удаления выглядит правильным, а вот почему не работает - не понятно, недостаточно сведений. Можно конечно поставить брейкпоинт и посмотреть, что содержит `Failure_Message`.

Comment: Кстати, а зачем его удалять, если его можно просто спрятать `Failure_Message.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`, потом зато не придется его добавлять. Вообще динамическое добавление - штука тяжелая и ненадежная. Управление видимостью намного быстрее работает.

Comment: @aepot автору вопроса нужно совершить маленькое открытие - узнать о существовании `UserControl`.

Comment: @Bulson `UserControl` в WPF - не частое решение, тем более для таких задач как панель нотификации, здесь 99% всей работы можно в xaml сделать с обычными контролами. Кстати, я тоже знаю умные слова: `ItemsControl`, `ItemTemplate`, `StyleTrigger`, `Binding`, могу продолжать так долго. И всё это ради того, чтобы не использовать `UserControl` :)

Comment: Автор, подскажите пожалуйста, какую задачу вы решаете и как оно должно выглядеть, и добавьте эту информацию в вопрос "Я хочу сделать...чтобы...". Быть может есть решение, которое позволит вам избежать этих танцев вокруг динамических контролов?

Comment: @aepot автор этого [курса](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/xaml-patterns/table-of-contents) вряд ли с вами согласится.

Comment: @Bulson сколько людей, столько и мнений. Как по мне, так `UserControl` - это когда нужны кастомные `DepencyProperty` или какое-то особое их поведение. В примере автора таковых не вижу.